# Open in the same windows (php file) other than a Iframe

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, iframe

I have this php file which pulls from my datebase

```
<?php
$cdb = new PDO('mysql:dbname=xxx;host=localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx');

foreach ($cdb->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 3") AS $img)

    {
    $twofirst = substr($img['hash'], 0, 2);
        echo '
                    <a style="position: relative; display: block; height: 140px;" href="/booru/post/view/' . $img['id'] . '" target="_blank">

                        <img src="booru/timthumb.php?src=images/' . $twofirst . '/' . $img['hash'] . '&h=125&w=125&q=100" width="125px" style="border-style: none"/>
                    </a>
                    ';

    }
```

Template

```
  <div class="section">
    <div class="secondaryContent">
            <h3>New Cosplays</h3>
              <iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="125px" height="400px" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 src="image.php">
              </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a better way I can get this to work?
If I don't add the `target="_blank"` It just opens the page in the Iframe which is not what I want

Someone say to use AJAX but I have no idea of how to even start if someone could maybe show me an example that would be great.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think there exists some other target you can use to get this effect. Don't remember exactly what it is, but try with "_top" or "_parent".

Comment: I'll add that as answer so you can accept.

Comment: Cheers I will in 7 mins :P too soon so it says thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use target="_top" instead of "_blank".